# How do I fix the "Can't place modded blocks in server" problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As you can see from the topic, I can't place modded blocks in my server, but in client, I can. Here is all the mods I added[image]

Please help me!! I wan't to play with my friends. Something that may help, I am not using the official Minecraft Launcher (If that has anything to do with my problem), I am using TerraminingMC Launcher Mac OS X version.http://terraminingmc.com/Launcher.html － Link
Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Plz help me!!

Comment: Does it work without mods?

Comment: Is the server a modded server? Or is it just a normal server?

Comment: We don't help with pirated content, try with a regular, non-cracked launcher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I Can't Place Modded Blocks on my Minecraft Server](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208231/i-cant-place-modded-blocks-on-my-minecraft-server)

Comment: this forum does not help with modded minecraft, at least from my experience

Comment: @hoodlamic1 Actually, the [consensus](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no) on that was that only crash and tech support questions relating to modded Minecraft are off-topic. This is fine, albeit technically illegal as the launcher the asker uses is not legitimate, and thus off-topic for a different reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serves has to have SAME mods installed (except rendering mods like OptiFine or minimaps, but all shown mods should be OK), and your server has to be FORGE server. You cannot use blocks or items from mods on server, which has no idea what the blocks are.

The reason why singleplayer works is because your CLIENT setups the "server", so having the mods installed.

You just need to find some tutorial with installing Forge server, as I know, this web is not supposed to be technical help for mods, it should be considered about gameplay.

Comment: @BlackThunder You are welcome.